# How can I reset a jMonthChooser and a jYearChooser?

Tags: java

For text fields `FieldName.setText(null);` can reset the field. How can I do the same for  `JMonthChooser` and `JYearChooser` fields to reset them to default values?

Comment: What is a JMonthChooser and a JYearChooser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to "reset" a `JYearChooser` field because its `setValue()` method takes a primitive `int` as argument. Therefore:

```
JYearChooser field = new JYearChooser();
field.setValue(null); // compile error
field.setValue(""); // compile error
```

Setting the year to a negative value doesn't work either.  Your best bet (which is what I have done) is to include a check box  that will enable or disable this component.  That way, you can do something like this:

```
if (field.isEnabled())
{
    // Do something
}
```

I needed to do this for a feature that I created to override values. Since I could not set these fields to blank, I needed something to ignore the field if an override wasn't required. This was the best I could come up with to work around that issue.

I assume that `JMonthChooser` has the same problem.  However, this is not the case for `JDateChooser`. For those field types, you can do the following to check if it is blank:

```
if (!(JTextField) prodStartDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText().equals(""))
{
    // Do something
}
```